# Magento 2 Bad Response: Client error: `POST https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions` resulted in a `400 Bad Request`

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, magento-2.2.5, payment-gateway, klarna

In Magento 2.2.5, I have configured "Klarna" Payment method using my valid credentials. But, In frontend when I go to the checkout page it is not showing the Klarna Payment Options.

I got this log:
https://pastebin.com/JgeunsuX

Thanks in advance.